# Pebble App Message

Tags: javascript

I am creating a [Pebble](https://getpebble.com/) Watch app where you press a button and it sends a message to a contact you configured when you press the select button. I have the configuration page working, but I need help trying to send a text message from the watch. I am aware you can request information from a website or your phone, but I do not know how to do this so I can send my watch message. I am using pebble JS and developing on cloudpebble on windows 8 (if that matters). Is there a way I can send a text from my watch using JS? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PebbleJS has the necessary ajax library to make calls to web  a service / API.
[PebbleJS-AJAX](http://pebble.github.io/pebblejs/#ajax)

Using AJAX you can make a call to a service like, [Twillo](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest) using their REST API. There are many more services that can also do this.

Your next option would be to build a companion app, but I don't think you were asking about that.

Good luck!